# 'Permission Denied' appears when attempted to install ise xilinx

Tags: software-installation, permissions, xilinx

When I tried to install ise xilinx on Ubuntu 13.04, I get `Permission denied`

Can anyone help me?

```
luaiks@luaiks-VPCEA22EA:~$ cd /home/luaiks/Downloads/Xilinx_ISE_DS_Lin_14.6_P.68d_3
luaiks@luaiks-VPCEA22EA:~/Downloads/Xilinx_ISE_DS_Lin_14.6_P.68d_3$ sudo chmod +x xsetup
luaiks@luaiks-VPCEA22EA:~/Downloads/Xilinx_ISE_DS_Lin_14.6_P.68d_3$ sudo ./xsetup
./xsetup: 18: ./xsetup: ./bin/lin64/xsetup: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 2):

I got it fine with the following command:

```
chmod -R 755 $directory
```

Here `$directory` is the directory that contains the ISE software, so in your case

```
 chmod -R 755 home/luaiks/Downloads/Xilinx_ISE_DS_Lin_14.6_P.68d_3
```

Answer (score 0):

It is worth mentioning that Xilinx ISE is not supposed to be working on Debian-based systems (please see the reason in [Xilinx mod's answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/987425/is-there-an-ide-other-than-xilinx-ise-for-fpga-programming-on-ubuntu-16-04)).

Xilinx dev team chose to develop ISE for SUSE and Red Hat systems only. Sometimes, installing it on Ubuntu will work, sometimes it won't, can't help it. Wasn't lucky myself, never worked on my 16.04.