# Is there an IDE other than Xilinx ISE for FPGA Programming on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, xilinx

I have this scholar project in which I have to program a Spartan 3 FPGA, but I encounter this problem where the associated IDE (i.e. Xilinx ISE) cannot be installed on Ubuntu 16.04. 
I was surprised at first because there is plenty of tutorials to launch Xilinx ISE on Ubuntu but after I encountered lots of errors when trying to install it, one of the Xilinx forum's admins [told me Ubuntu is not supported by the IDE.](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Installation-and-Licensing/Could-not-set-the-path-for-installing-Xilinx-ISE-Design-Suite/m-p/814783#M20081)

Long story short, I'm looking for an equivalent software that would ease FPGA programming for the target platform that is the Spartan 3 families.

I know we're not supposed to advertise any product on .SE sites but I'd mostly like to know if such software exist.

Thanks guys!

Comment: I do not know about Xilinx ISE, but Altera/Intel Quartus works on Ubuntu 16.04. Try to [search on the net](https://www.google.ru/search?q=ise+14.7+ubuntu&newwindow=1&safe=off&source=lnt&tbs=qdr:y&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj16vjg3ZPYAhXnFJoKHW5uDDUQpwUIIQ&biw=1360&bih=589) about installation of ISE on Ubuntu. I think it is possible - see [link1](https://embeddedmicro.com/tutorials/mojo-software-and-updates/installing-ise) and [link2](https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/25987597). It works even [on ArchLinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xilinx_ISE_WebPACK).

Comment: @N0rbert thanks for the details. Unfortunately I absolutely need to work on Ubuntu 16.04 (for the other requirements of my project), and your search suggestion also leads to an admin's answer saying Ubuntu is not supported by Xilinx ISE. I'll try Altera, though I'm not much of a believer since Spartan 3 is Xilinx's technology. Maybe there's an **open-source IDE** that would do nicely?